# Firebase referencia con child variable

Tags: android, firebase

Reformulo la pregunta. Se podria hacer de alguna manera para poder contar los votos con esta base de datos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que me faltaría poner bien el child para que me recogiera todos los uid de los usuarios

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "Events" ).child( code ).child( mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid() );
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Event event = dataSnapshot.getValue( Event.class );

            List<String> usuarios = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                usuarios.add(childSnapshot.child("vote").getValue(String.class));

                Log.e("nombre ", usuarios+" estos son los usuarios OK");
                }
```

Comment: En tu estructura la referencia correcta sería: `Events/123/Users/CAAADAUSUARIO/votes` ... estamos **ante una estructura desaconsejada por la documentación** porque para encontrar los votos tienes que entrar en el nodo de **caaaada usuario**. Esto no es factible ni a nivel de eficacia, ni a nivel de seguridad (permisos). [Lee lo que dice Firebase, especialmente en la sección **Crear datos escalables**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/structure-data?hl=es-419), el ejemplo propuesto se puede aplicar a tu caso, creando un nodo de votos donde guardes el voto de cada usuario.

Comment: Gracias Cedano le pegare un vistazo

Comment: Como ya han comentado arriba, la estructura que tienes es ineficiente (ya que la estructura de Firebase no lo maneja bien).
La solución que planeta @Gaston es buena ya que resuelve el problema a corto plazo pero podría no escalar en el tiempo. Mi recomendación es que lleves un contador y lo actualices a mano cada vez que se agrega un like. Idealmente te recomiendo utilizar una [Firebase function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) para automatizar esta tarea.

Comment: Asi lo he hecho al final, como me ha comentado Gaston que al final es también como lo comento A. Cedano poniendo la doc de Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo tengo una estructura para contar la cantidad de likes de ciertos posts de mis usuarios. Para hacerlo mas facil , afuera del nodo Users que tienes crea otro que se llame Votos, adentro de Votos guardas el UID del usuario y abajo los votos con push() , con el valor true, asi, luego lo unico que haces es entrar a ese nodo Votos y con `getChildrenCount();` dependiendo al usuario podes contar la cantidad de votos que tiene

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de mi estructura para contar la cantidad de likes que tiene dicha foto, lo explico como lo deberias tener vos aunque el mio sea distinto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui en cambio de Likes vas a tener Votos , este es un nodo separado a Users, no adentro de Users

ahora, lo unico que te queda es acceder a ese nodo con el UID del usuario y obtener los hijos para poder saber la cantidad, de esta manera no te haria falta un for si quieres saber la cantidad de votos de cada usuario

```
public void countVote(){
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "Events" ).child( code ).child("Users").child("Votos").child(userID);
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            long cantVotos  = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    } );

}
```

para agregar el voto del usuario a Votos lo unico que haces es esto

Primero yo separaria la referencia para no tenerla declarada toda junta

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Votos");
```

y luego pongo el valor del usuario cuando vota

```
mDatabase.child(userID).push().setValue(true);
```

PD: si no queres usar el uid del usuario, podes usar el mail mismo que usas en Users

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Gastón, esta semana probaré a hacerlo como me has dicho y ya te diré el resultado, un saludo

Comment: ningun problema, me avisas si te sirvio, un saludo

Comment: Al final he creado en la bbdd votos-code-uiD, asi me cuenta los votos en general ahora tendre que mirar para que me cuente los trues y los falses. Gracias por la ayuda